# React uncheck all checkboxes on page using separate button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a table with multiple checkboxes, one for each row.

```
          {filteredData.map((entry, index) => (
            <tr className='tr' key={entry.id}>
              <td className='td:first-child'>
              <input type="checkbox"
                id={`checkbox-${entry.id}`}
                checked={checkboxes[index]}
                onClick={() => handleCheckboxChange(entry)}
                onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
                onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}/>
              </td>...
```

and the coresponding handler that fills some textboxes with the values from the table row when the checkbox is checked and also clears the textboxes when the checkbox is unchecked:

```
function handleCheckboxChange(entry)
  {
    entry.selected = !entry.selected;
    
    selectedValues.push(entry);
    
    // If the entry is selected, add it to the selectedValues array, otherwise remove it
    if (entry.selected)
    {
      selectedValues.push(entry);

      const index = selectedValues.findIndex((item) => item.id === entry.id);
    
      if (index !== -1)
      {
        setIndex(`${entry.id}`);
        setVar1(selectedValues[0].var1);
        setVar2(selectedValues[0].var2);
      
        selectedValues.pop();
    
      }
    }
    else
    {
      handleClearText();
        setVar3("");
    }
  }
```

and a "Clear Text" button that should clear some fields but not others and also uncheck any checked checkboxes:

```
<button id="ClearButton" className="button-editField" type="button" onClick={handleClearText} style={{marginLeft: '30px'}}>Clear Text</button>
```

and the constant,hook and handler:

```
const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckboxes(Array(filteredData.length));
  }, [filteredData]);

  const handleClearText = (e) => {
    setVar1("");
    setVar2("");
 
    setCheckboxes(Array(filteredData.length).fill(false));
    
    const updatedData =  filteredData.map((entry) => ({
      ...entry,
      selected: !entry.selected,
    }));

    filteredData = updatedData;
  }
```

The button does Clear the TextFields and sets all checkboxes to unchecked, but it looks like it only does so graphically, because when clicking a previously selected checkbox, it doesn't get checked until it is pressed a third time.

Initially i only did `setCheckboxes(Array(filteredData.length).fill(false));` and thought it might have something to do with the `entry.selected` property, but while I console logged the states, this property seems to be set just as expected.

Expected behaviour: check -> textboxes get filled -> click clear button -> checkboxes get emptied and everything gets unchecked -> check same row again
-> textboxes get filled and checkbox gets ticked *(whereas now the else branch gets executed)*

```
else
    {
      handleClearText();
        setVar3("");
    }
```

What am I missing?